# GeoServer GroupLayer GetFeatureInfo returns wrong layer feature

Tags: geoserver, style, zoom, getfeatureinfo, group-layer

I'm currently facing an issue with GeoServer and its GroupLayer functionality. I have created a GroupLayer named `confini` containing three layers: `tutorial:Reg01012023_WGS84` (Regions), `tutorial:ProvCM01012023_WGS84` (Provinces), and `tutorial:Com01012023_WGS84` (Communes).

Each layer is associated with a default style that controls its visibility based on the map scale. The Regions layer should be visible when the map scale is less than 1:4000000, the Provinces layer between 1:4000000 and 1:500000, and the Communes layer when the scale is greater than 1:500000.
Moreover, the user should be able to click anywhere on the map to see more information regarding the currently displayed Layer via a GetFeatureInfo call to the GroupLayer.

---

The issue I'm facing is that although the map displays the layers correctly based on the zoom level, the GetFeatureInfo requests made to the GroupLayer seem to be "out of sync" with the current zoom level.

For example, when the map is zoomed to such a level that the Provinces layer has just replaced the Regions layer, the GetFeatureInfo request returns a feature corresponding to a Region instead. However, if I slightly increase the zoom level, the GetFeatureInfo request returns a Province as expected. The same behaviour happens between Provinces and Communes.

This issue is not specific to my implementation, as I have also tested it in QGIS by connecting to the GroupLayer provided by GeoServer, and the same strange behavior occurs.

---

Here is a code snippet of the style I'm using:
Regions:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
        <NamedLayer>
            <Name>not-highlighted-regions</Name>
            <UserStyle>
                <Title>Not highlighted regions Layer Style</Title>
                <FeatureTypeStyle>
                    <Rule>
                        <MinScaleDenominator>4000000</MinScaleDenominator>
                        <PolygonSymbolizer>
                            ...
                        </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    </Rule>
                </FeatureTypeStyle>
            </UserStyle>
        </NamedLayer>
    </StyledLayerDescriptor>

Provinces: 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
        <NamedLayer>
            <Name>not-highlighted-provinces</Name>
            <UserStyle>
                <Title>Not Highlighted Provinces Layer Style</Title>
                <FeatureTypeStyle>
                    <Rule>
                        <MinScaleDenominator>500000</MinScaleDenominator>
                        <MaxScaleDenominator>4000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                        <PolygonSymbolizer>
                            ...
                        </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    </Rule>
                </FeatureTypeStyle>
            </UserStyle>
        </NamedLayer>
    </StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Communes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>not-highlighted-regions</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>Not highlighted regions Layer Style</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>4000000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        ...
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

GetFeatureInfo url:

```
SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.1.1
&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo
&SRS=EPSG:4326
&BBOX=4.779052734375001,40.396764305572056,17.852783203125004,46.79253827035982
&WIDTH=1190
&HEIGHT=805
&INFO_FORMAT=application/json
&X=453
&Y=143
&FEATURE_COUNT=50
&BUFFER=0
&LAYERS=tutorial:confini
&QUERY_LAYERS=tutorial:confini
```

---

How can I resolve this issue between the GroupLayer and GetFeatureInfo?

Is there a configuration or setting that needs to be adjusted to ensure that the GetFeatureInfo requests return the correct features based on the visible layer in the GroupLayer?

---

Edit: as Ian suggested, the problem was DPI related. I was using the react-leaflet `detectRetina={true}` prop to improve the sharpness of the map, but It seems that by removing it from the map and its child components the problem is solved.

Comment: technically you're missing parameters to create the image in the GetFeatureInfo request ~ Image format and style used.

Comment: It's probably a DPI mismatch, but unless you can reproduce it using standard layers or provide a script to load the data with example URLs then it's unlikely to get any one to look at it